# How to re-ask an old question which is not answered yet?

Tags: discussion, questions

I ask lots of questions, they stay unanswered yet and the number of their views is too low.

For example these:

- [How to set focus on next input in Jquery autocomplete item select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071367/how-to-set-focus-on-next-input-in-jquery-autocomplete)
- [How to update tree view control values into database in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820061/how-to-update-tree-view-control-values-into-database-in-asp-net)

How to re-ask the questions?

Comment: What is exactly your problem? **All of your 11 questions are answered** (you did not (yet) *accept* only 2 of them).

Comment: @Jongware  actually these questions are impotent for me and i realize it was pretty off-base the first time thats why :P

Comment: Related on MSE: [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/238706)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't.

You edit the question to make it better. This will bump the question to the homepage where it will get new views and hopefully an answer.

You place a bounty on the question. This will promote the question so it get's new views and hopefully an answer.

All that reasking the question will lead to is closure and possible down-votes.

Comment: Okay you mean to say if i change the title of the question it will be again showing in current questions list ? @ChrisF

Comment: @GarimaRawat - yes, but only if the change is valid.

Answer (score -4):

What is about an "voting" option, like the stars, so everybody sees how many people regardless of their points left for bounties have the same question.
Also you may come back to the question, if during a long workday you managed to solve it.

Comment: What kind of voting option?

Comment: like "14 other people would like to know an answer to this question".
wait a moment, that means the same functionality as the voting system that already exsits, sorry for posting.