# Having same unanswered question with more details to provide

Tags: discussion, edits, duplicate-questions

How to handle situation, where original OP is not following on the question, I have same problem and I can provide additional information?

Example Q: [Git slow sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486926/git-slow-sometimes)

I'm in same situation and I'd like to work on resolution of the question. However all my additional details would cause edit rejects, I cannot add my details as an answer (make no sense), and I would like to avoid spamming comments. Also, if I would open my own question, it would be clearly a duplicate to the question.

Thanks for any suggestions.

I have checked following:

- [How to re-ask an old question which is not answered yet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272468/how-to-re-ask-an-old-question-which-is-not-answered-yet)
- [I have the same exact question as an existing unanswered question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273067/i-have-the-same-exact-question-as-an-existing-unanswered-question)

Comment: As a note, your question cannot be closed as a duplicate of the other one, were you to ask one, because the original does not have an answer. So, you _could_ post your own question with the extra details. Personally, I would wait until your bounty is over. Someone might answer, with that bounty on the question, and then asking your own becomes needless. At least, hopefully becomes needless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bounty with message explaining the exact part you are looking (as you've done) is the preferred approach.

If you can't explain variation in bounty's comment - there is a good chance you have different problem that just sounds similar. It is ok to ask new question in this case. Make sure to show your research and in particular link to old question with clarification why your one is different.