# How am I supposed to contribute to an unanswered question that I share?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I have an identical question as: [Disable automatic generation of opening parenthesis in scala by Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43173642/8031185) and I want to add additional information, but I don't know how. The information that I want to contribute is:

> Failing to remove the parentheses can trigger the 'unnecessary parentheses' inspection, which means that Intellij actually should know when it would be unnecessary to add parentheses, but adds them regardless.

I have looked up and attempted the below methods, but they have been uneffective.

- I cannot [answer the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), because I simply do not know the answer. I have additional information about the problem, but it doesn't seem to resolve anything so it wouldn't actually be an answer.
- I lack the required reputation (currently 16) in order to add the information [as a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).
- I also lack the required reputation to [place a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) as suggested [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345425/8031185).
- I attempted to suggest an edit as suggested [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272469/8031185), but it [was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20414783).

The simple  answer might be to just gain more reputation to cover some of the above, but as a beginner, I lack the knowledge to answer other questions.

I also do not feel as though I would be able to ask good questions since, in general, the information about what I want to learn is already available. 
If I have a problem learning, it's probably because I have trouble understanding the information. It would be difficult to resolve this issue by someone explaining it at me, a back-and-forth discussion would likely be more suitable.

Comment: Usually it's the "funny but valid" questions that get a lot of upvotes (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521158/in-python-why-does-0xbin-return-false), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270127/can-a-1-a-2-a-3-ever-evaluate-to-true)) instead of the "good but obscure ones".

Comment: If it's additional information about the problem, wouldn't a suggested edit adding this information would be the way to go, to improve the question?

Comment: The last paragraph of this question may mean that even working to contribute to that question may not even be the way to go. If you are think that a _back-and_forth discussion_ is what you need to fix your problem, SO model may not be what you are looking for. Try [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/), it may be more useful to your needs.

Comment: @yivi That would be accurate for when I am trying to learn something new and information is available, as I had mentioned. However, this is a case where I have a problem where there appears to be no information available for it, besides the very question I have linked (and the question it links).

Comment: @yivi "wouldn't a suggested edit adding this information would be the way to go" - Doesn't he mention that he tried that?

Comment: I do not know if you are addressing my first or second comment.

Comment: Clarified......

Comment: @superphonic My previous comment was meant for the OP, but your comment came just in the middle and now everything is very confusing :P. Regarding the suggested edit, I still think it could be the way to go... but if the question asker rejects the edits, I guess a new question would be the way to go, IMO. Can't be a duplicate, since that question doesn't have an answer. And the OP can add additional information (as the intended edit) to make the question better. An additional problem may be than the OP doesn't really think a q&a would be the way to go to actually fix their problem...

Comment: I had this problem once, long ago, and posted as an answer. It was not a *solution* but a detailed explanation of the behavior, why another answer "worked" (said answer was just a work-around that really wasn't for some use-cases), and some other observations intended to give insight into the problem at hand for future readers (got a comment that the behavior was, in fact, a known bug that the company did nothing other than confirm that it existed for a good 15 years). May not have been the best idea, but it was what I could do at the time.

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325860/1394393

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It seems to me that you already have the answers you seek:

- A suggested edit might be the best "solution", but the original asker rejected it. Sad, but that's their prerogative.
- Commenting would also be good, but you need to earn another 34 reputation points (just 17 good edits, for example). Why not do that? You would be there in no time at all, I think.
- Finally, since that question doesn't have an answer and the asker is not amenable to improvements, I do not think posting a new question with additional details and more information would be bad on itself. If your question got answered, the older one could be flagged as a duplicate to yours.

Comment: I think you really misunderstood the last paragraph in the question. That paragraph is not about the Scala/IntelliJ question but more a general explanation why he doesn't ask so many questions (thus not getting rep points from questions). His point is, he doesn't have the rep for comments and feels unable to aquire points quickly by answering or asking.

Comment: @jps You are probably right and I may have misunderstood that last paragraph. I didn't find it particularly clear or relevant to the rest of the question, so I guess I may have misinterpreted it. But I still think that the other points stand.

Comment: yes, I agree with the other points. And earning some rep is important to at least beeing able to comment. You can see the problem in the LQ queue every day.

Comment: @jps That's exactly what I meant, about asking questions and rep.

Comment: I just discovered somewhat of a workaround that can help with the problem I had linked (the scala parentheses Intellij question). I'm going to post what I found as an answer as I believe it at least merits being a partial answer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). However, I'm not sure what to do about this question (about contribution to shared questions). @yivi's points are valid, though I didn't actually achieve what I wanted by following them.

Comment: @JAKZero : yivi's second point is to edit other questions and answers. If you see posts that are generally ok but just need some tweeks, fixing of grammar, formatting the code etc, you could earn 2 points per edit And there are hundreds of posts in need of good edits. This way you could easily earn enough to reach 50 rep points soon.

Comment: Instead of 17 good edits, I would advice on simply one good answer with 4 upvotes. Or a mix.